# How to change pass a struct to a function by reference in c

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct player{

    int life;

};struct player info;

void name(struct player *info);

int main(void)
{

    info.life = 20;
    name(&info);

    printf(">>>>%d", info.life);
return 0;
}

void name(struct player *info)
{
    info.life = 20
}
```

Hi, well this is just a practice code I am trying to pass a struct to a function by reference, but how do  I change the value of the int in the struct? when i try to compile 
info.life  = 20; I get an error, what am i doing wrong? I also tried doing 
*info.life = 20; but I also got an error. Thanks you guys! :)

Comment: Try a number besides 20 so you know it worked.

Comment: @CharlieBurns lol. its the little things =P

Comment: `*info.life` is correct--almost. Try `(*info).life`. Of course, using `->` is better style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually typedef my structs to make it more readable.

```
typedef struct _Player
{
  int life;
} Player;
```

Then to access your struct or pass it in you would do:

```
void name(Player *pInfo)
{
  pInfo->life = 20;
}
```

I also prepend a p for any pointer variable, so that you can easily see when you have a pointer or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
void name(struct player *info)
{
    info.life = 20;
}
```

that should be `info->life`. because `info` is a pointer.